# So I made a program that prints Pascal's Triangle in C++ & Java and for some reason it starts breaking when I make 14+ rows?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

long factorial(long n)
{
    int x = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) x = x * i;
    return x;
}

long nCr(long n, long r)
{
    return factorial(n) / (factorial(r) * factorial(n - r));
}

int main()
{
    int row;
    std::cout << "Enter the number of rows: ";
    std::cin >> row;
    for (int n = 1; n <= row; n++)
    {
        for (int s = 1; s <= row - n; s++) std::cout << " "; //space
        for (int r = 0; r != n; r++) std::cout << nCr(n-1, r) << " "; //numbers
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    
}
```

The code works perfectly fine when constructing a 13-row Pascal's Triangle(albeit a bit ugly), but for some reason it starts becoming inaccurate/wrong at the 14th row and prints this:

```
             1
            1 1
           1 2 1
          1 3 3 1
         1 4 6 4 1
        1 5 10 10 5 1
       1 6 15 20 15 6 1
      1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1
     1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1
    1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1
   1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1
  1 11 55 165 330 462 462 330 165 55 11 1
 1 12 66 220 495 792 924 792 495 220 66 12 1
1 4 24 88 221 399 532 532 399 221 88 24 4 1
```

Comment: `13! = 6227020800 > LONG_MAX = 2147483647` (note that `LONG_MAX` is implementation dependent, but this is the "usual" value)

Comment: The elements in Pascal's triangle follow a simple [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) which avoids integer overflows for the representable numbers.

Comment: I changed the functions' data type to an unsigned long long and it still can't calculate 13!.

Comment: As mentioned the size of the type `long` is implementation defined. It could be either a signed 32 or 64 bit integer. Use e.g. `unsigned long long` to get a type that is at last 64 bits (and is unsigned, which gives you further range, and makes sense since you should not have negative values).

Comment: Oh I got it now, all I changed was the factorial function's data type, not the data type of the variable it returns.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it'll be better to recommend `uint64_t` rather than spamming `unsigned long long` everywhere, isn't it?

Comment: Why are you even calculating a factorial? You can simply use a `std::vector` sized to the exponent and then calculate the coefficient values directly updating the values held in the array as you go. Much less computationally expensive.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Pascals Triangle is to **avoid** the calculation of big factorials. See, how many multiplactions you need to make. And by calculating the combinations, n choose k, you quickly come to situations, where build in datatypes overflow.

To tackle such problems, Pascals Triangle is the ideal solution. You can survive, by just summing up values. Row by row.

There are really many solutions for that. I show an example using 2 `std::vector`s. One holds the current row (the upper row) and the other the next row. For the next row, we can just add the values from the upper row. That is really simple.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>

using ull = unsigned long long;

constexpr size_t NumberOfRows = 50U;

int main() {

    std::vector<ull> current{ 1 };
    std::vector<ull> next{};

    current.reserve(NumberOfRows+2);next.reserve(NumberOfRows+3);

    for (size_t i{}; i < NumberOfRows; ++i) {

        // Next row has one element more
        next.resize(current.size() + 1);

        // Each row starts and ends with a 1
        next.front() = 1; next.back() = 1;

        // For the next row, sum up the upper to values from the current row
        for (unsigned k{ 1 }; k < next.size() - 1; ++k)
            next[k] = current[k - 1] + current[k];
        
        // Debug Output
        std::cout << std::setw(NumberOfRows - i + 2) << "";
        std::copy(current.begin(), current.end(), std::ostream_iterator<ull>(std::cout, " ")); 
        std::cout << '\n';

        // Prepare next loop run. Assign the calculated row to current
        current = std::move(next);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you calculate factorial(n) you are overflowing LONG_MAX. By doing an unsigned long you get more positive integers but this will only push the maximum rows a few more. If you know that your doing factorial division you can remove a lot of the large numbers by changing the logic.
ie: 13! /11! = (13 * 12 * 11 * 10 * 9....) / (11 * 10 * 9...)
can be simplified to (13* 12) which will remove the overflow